# Display Ansi colors from log

Tags: linux, bash, colors

On a linux terminal

I have logs with ANSII colors like this

```
03-25 21:01:19.451  8067  8138 I ReactNativeJS: '\u001b[34m', '================================', '\u001b[0m'
```

and I would like to be able to display them with their ANSII color

```
> adb logcat | [magic-to-be-found]
```

or better and I would like to filter and display them with their ANSII color

```
> adb logcat | grep ReactNative | [magic-to-be-found]
```

**example with tail**

- this command show no colors

```
>tail adb.log | xargs -i -d '\n' unbuffer echo -e "{}"
04-01 20:21:06.867  5351  5421 I ReactNativeJS: '\u001b[33m', 'opened', '\u001b[0m'
04-01 20:21:07.650  5351  5421 I ReactNativeJS: '\u001b[33m', 'request :', '/AA   PUT', '', '\u001b[0m'
04-01 20:21:09.253  5351  5421 I ReactNativeJS: '\u001b[33m', 'request :', '/bb', '\u001b[0m'
04-01 20:21:16.643  5351  5421 I ReactNativeJS: '\u001b[34m', '================================', '\u001b[0m'
```

- while echo of one of the lines does show right ansi
  color :

```
>echo -e "04-01 20:21:16.643  5351  5421 I ReactNativeJS: '\u001b[34m', '================================', '\u001b[0m'"
04-01 20:21:16.643  5351  5421 I ReactNativeJS: '', '================================', ''
```

Comment: From: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#outputFormat it seems `-v color` should do it

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi

"- color: Show each priority level with a different color. "
not what I want I want to get the colors from the escape sequences

Answer (score 0):

Try to pipe your command to `less -R`, e.g.

```
tail adb.log | xargs -i -d '\n' unbuffer echo -e "{}" | less -R
```

see `man less`.